# Как использовать интерфейсы?

Tags: php, веб-программирование

Не могу понять, как использовать интерфейсы. Нашел вот такой пример:

```
<?php
class LogToDatabase 
{
    public function execute($message)
    {
        var_dump('log the message to a database :'.$message);
    }
}
class LogToFile 
{
    public function execute($message)
    {
        var_dump('log the message to a file :'.$message);
    }
}
class UsersController 
{ 
    protected $logger;
    
    public function __construct(LogToFile $logger)
    {
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }
    
    public function show()
    { 
        $user = 'nahid';
        $this->logger->execute($user);
    }
}
$controller = new UsersController(new LogToFile);
$controller->show();
```

В статье пишут, допустим, если мы захотим использовать не LogToFile, а LogToDataBase, то понадобится интерфейс. Так в чём проблема в конструкторе UsersController не указывать сам класс и потом просто можно вызывать тот класс, который тебе нужен.

Comment: "и потом просто можно вызывать тот класс, который тебе нужен." --- поясни что имеешь в виду

Comment: "Так в чём проблема в конструкторе UsersController не указывать сам класс" --- там и не указывается класс, там указывается интерфейс.....а какой конкретно будет класс - неизвестно. В этом и смысл

Comment: ну вот смотрите, в конструкторе класса UsersController указан LogToFile (в параметрах), его можно убрать и потом при создании объекта этого класса, можно указать тот класс, который тебе нужен

Comment: А как ты узнаешь какой тебе нужен? и при создании какого объекта идёт речь?

Comment: Алексей, так человек, который пишет код, он же не тупой, он укажет тот класс, который ему нужен))))) Все равно не понятно, зачем они :)

Comment: Ну вот есть фреймворк с настройками.... кто-то использует фреймворк....как разработчики фреймворка должны узнать  кто какой класс будет использовать **другой разработчик** из другой компании другой страны?

Comment: И почему ты решил, что сейчас нужен один класс, а потом не понадобится другой? третий? четвертый? на дев один, для отладки второй, для прода третий? для отладки четвертый

Comment: А зачем тогда использовать интерфейс в маленьком проекте, где по факту файлов 5-7 + к тому-же, ты пишешь для себя, не для кого-то, зачем тогда их использовать?))))))

Comment: А если вам не сложно, расскажите пожалуйста про абстрактные классы))))

Comment: Где в тексте вопроса есть упоминание "маленького проекта"?

Comment: ну это я в пример поставил, просто видел такое))

Comment: в зависимости от проектов, сложности, типа, назначения - применяются те или иные подходы....вот лично на моём сайте визитке вообще нет даже никакого MVC и ООП... от слова совсем.... так что применять всё с умом, а не забивать гвозди микроскопом

Comment: если вам не сложно, посмотритету статью, там ниже есть абстрактный класс https://web-programming.com.ua/ponimanie-ispolzovaniya-interfejsa-i-abstraktnogo-klassa-v-php/ пишут в ней, что нужно удалить дублированный код, зачем? Когда вызываешь класс, а потом метод, он не берется с другого класса

Comment: смысл интерфейсов в том, что мы не знаем, что захотим использовать или, возможно. поменяем свои желания, выберем другой тип, но того же назначение.... как я писал - например для отладки будет один тип логирования, для ДЕВ версии - вторая, для ПРОДа - третий. Всё что нужно будет для интерфейсов - это указать нужный класс Логгера в настройках приложения.....

Comment: второй пример - с приложением можно взаимодействовать через UI, а можно через терминал. вон в браузере перевод строки это "<br>", а в терминале линукса "\n"  ...вот и два разных класса для вывода информации нужно (утрированно)....а заранее разработчик не сможет никогда узнать как именно захочет работать пользователь......